# iOS stream live h.264 video

Tags: ios, streaming, live, h.264

I have a video stream with mime type video/h264 that streams live h.264 video from a security camera. I am trying to stream this real time and decode the h.264 frames (preferably hardware decode) and display them in a view. I have looked extensively for libraries or frameworks to support this but am not exactly sure which is the right approach. I have looked a little bit at the AVFoundation but not sure how to handle the video/h264 stream. Should I be grabbing each frame (I frame / P frame) from the stream and passing it the AVAssetReader? Any direction / sample code / library references would be extremely helpful!

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: {date}
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: -1
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=myboundary
Set-Cookie: stream={stream-id}; version=1

--myboundary
Content-Type: video/h264
Sync-Point: "yes" or "no"
Pre-roll: "yes" or "no"
Media-Start: "invalid" or {mediastart}
Media-End: "invalid" or {mediaend}
Stream-Start: "invalid" or {stream start time}
Stream-End: "invalid" or {stream end time}
Content-Length: {content-length}
X-Date: {x-date}

{image}
```

Comment: What protocol does your camera use, HLS,Rtsp,mjpeg

Comment: Well the camera itself is being streamed via RTSP, however I am speaking to a video surveillance server that does NOT speak RTSP. Instead it just has a multipart HTTP stream with mimetype video/h264. I believe it is just a stream of NAL units.

Comment: You mean some proprietary format, not HLS, you need to decode the nalu's, is there any kind of documentation, you need to decode the header to determine the packet structure, I think

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Date: {date}\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store\r\n
Expires: -1\r\n
Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=myboundary\r\n
Set-Cookie: stream={stream-id}; version=1\r\n
\r\n
[--myboundary\r\n
Content-Type: video/h264\r\n
Sync-Point: "yes" or "no" \r\n
Pre-roll: "yes" or "no" \r\n
Media-Start: "invalid" or {mediastart} \r\n
Media-End: "invalid" or {mediaend} \r\n
Stream-Start: "invalid" or {stream start time} \r\n
Stream-End: "invalid" or {stream end time} \r\n
Content-Length: {content-length}\r\n
X-Date: {x-date}\r\n
\r\n
{image}
\r\n]

Comment: That is hard to read there but that is the specification for this stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot play elementary h.264 on iOS. Your workaround can be to wrap it in a mp4 or ts stream before playing [http pd download or hls]. But unless you compile something else (like ffmpeg) onto the device you will not be able to play raw h.264

Comment: That makes a lot sense, ffmpeg can decode h264, here's a couple starting points both of these will require a bit of work to play raw h264 https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/WebStreamX_flv_demo https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie of the two webstreamX can handle a streamed file and plays flv's mov files quite well. Not sure about kxmovie, you have to move your files to the device